# Nagios NTP, discarding peer

Tags: ntp, nagios

We're using nagios *check_ntp_time* for monitoring time on our servers. Unfortunately the service is flapping. And reporting a lot of false-positives. It happens everytime for random server in random day time and lasts for ~10-30 minutes. When the problem occurs we get:

```
watch01:~ # /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ntp_time -H lb01 -w 1 -c 2 -v
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.07509887218
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.07508444786
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.07499825954
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.07510817051
discarding peer 0: stratum=0
overall average offset: 0
NTP CRITICAL: Offset unknown|
```

When everything is ok, we get (I used different server to not have to wait):

```
watch01:~ # /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ntp_time -H web02 -w 1 -c 2 -v
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.0002282857895
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.0002194643021
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.0002347230911
sending request to peer 0
response from peer 0: offset 0.0002293586731
overall average offset: 0.0002282857895
NTP OK: Offset 0.0002282857895 secs|offset=0.000228s;1.000000;2.000000;
```

We are using:

- check_ntp_time v1.4.15 (nagios-plugins 1.4.15) on Debian squeeze.

Remote ntp daemon is:

- ntpd - NTP daemon program - Ver. 4.2.4p4

I already found some forums where the problem is described: [1](http://forums.meulie.net/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=6841), [2](https://bugs.op5.com/view.php?id=4049), [3](http://tech.akom.net/index.php?url=archives/27-Nagios-check_ntp-quits-working-in-2009-with-Offset-unknown.html&serendipity[csuccess]=moderate#feedback). Every time they edvise to upgrade nagios-plugins, because in version prior to *1.4.13* there was a bug with inserted leap second. But we have already newer version of *nagios-plugins*.

Comment: Check if the peer is actually reporting a stratum of zero. If so, it's NTP on the machine. If not, it's Nagios.

Comment: This issue still exists after upgrading to 1.4.16

Comment: I recall having to modify the check_ntp script to remove that check. It has been a long time. Do some grepping for that error in the check_script and see if you can't work around your problem.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/625027/nagios-check-ntp-time-offset-unknown/626286#626286

Answer (score 1):

Maybe still exists in 1.4.15: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=397597&aid=3314686&group_id=29880